# Proguard causes problems with SSL keystore on Android

Tags: android, obfuscation, ssl-certificate, proguard, keystore

In an Android app, I fetch content from a https url; in order to avoid SSL cert verification errors, I add the SSL public key to my keystore, which then resides in my res/raw folder of the app.
Following the instructions as on http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html, which all works fine so far.

..until I activate Proguard and obfuscation. With Proguard activated, I am getting the following error,

```
ERROR/Login(4401): Could not login.
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <store.mydomain.com/185.165.192.15> != <store.mydomain.com> OR <store.mydomain.com>
    at xyz.fd.a(Unknown Source)
```

which I don't quite understand. Why would the idenfitication of the url change in a way that it's also fetching the `/<ipAddress>` together with the domain name, whereas it works fine without Proguard obfuscation.

As the httpClient for fetching the https content, I use sources as in MyHttpClient at:
http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html

proguard.cfg:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference

-keep class * extends DefaultHttpClient

-ignorewarnings
-repackageclasses 'xyz'
-allowaccessmodification

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Update:

Also removing -repackageclasses 'xyz' and -allowaccessmodification doesn't make a difference, same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the latest httpclient 4.1.2. Now when I switch back to 4.1.1, the problem is gone.

Also see: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.httpclient.user/262